# Unable to read Images from xcode project in iPad IOS 10.2.1 64bit when download app from app store (testflight)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uiimageview, uiimage

Unable to read Images from xcode project for example.
drag and drop one image to xcode project, then read using following code.

__weak NSString *strTemp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/s_%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],[[self.arr_gallery objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"filename_larger"]];

```
            strTemp = [strTemp substringToIndex:[strTemp length]-3];

            strTemp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@png",strTemp];
```

//                NSString *strTemp = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/s_BGP001@2x.png",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];

```
            UIImage *image;

            image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:strTemp];

            img.image = image;

            strTemp = nil;
```

Comment: What do you get if you `NSLog("%@", strTemp)`?

Comment: Also, I'd change the variable name to something more revealing, such as `imagePath`.

Comment: does it work on different devices?

Comment: Yes it;s work with 32 bit device.

Comment: Thanks Sekalf Nroc - I have checked it's getting nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write following code.

```
 NSString *newStrTemp = [strTemp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"jpg" withString:@"png"];
```

Instead of this one.

```
strTemp = [strTemp substringToIndex:[strTemp length]-3];
strTemp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@png",strTemp];
```